# NETXJS: transfer data from page to component with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Hey how are you? i'm using nextjs / styled components and i would like to change a string via props. I made a layout component with a main and it has an props to make it dinamic per page

**Page 'prueba.js'**

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/Layout/Layout';

const prueba = () => {

    const setNewBackground = 'green';

    console.log(setNewBackground)

    return ( 
        <Layout setNewBackground={setNewBackground}>
            <p>holaaaaa</p>
        </Layout>    
     );
}
 
export default prueba;
```

**Layout.js component**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Main from './Main';

const Layout = props => {

    const [background, setBackground] = useState('blue')

    const setNewBackground = () => {
        setBackground (background);
    }

    return (
        <>
        <Main newBackground={background}>
            {props.children}
        </Main>
        </>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

And Main.js component

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

    const Main = styled.main`
        background:${props => props.newBackground};
        height:100vh;
        width:100%;
    `;
    
    export default Main;
```

I check it in console but it shows me undefined. Wheres the error :(? thanks and have a good year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a state for that. You can use only the color prop you passed to the Layout.

Prueba.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/Layout/Layout';

const prueba = () => {
    return ( 
        <Layout backgroundColor='green'>
            <p>holaaaaa</p>
        </Layout>    
     );
}
 
export default prueba;
```

Layout.js

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Main from './Main';

const Layout = ({ backgroundColor, chidlren }) => {
    return (
        <Main backgroundColor={backgroundColor}>
            {children}
        </Main>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

Main.js

```js
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

const Main = styled.main`
    background:${({ backgroundColor }) => backgroundColor || 'your default color'};
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
`;
    
export default Main;
```